# How to display Napili community in iframe on third-party domain?

Tags: napili, iframe, clickjacking

I am trying to display Napili community in a iframe on external domain but I am hitting the below error:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options:
>   https://tryeverrything-developer-edition.na50.force.com/s/ does not
>   permit cross-origin framing.

[image]

I have enabled the framing by any page as shown in the below screenshot but still it is not working.

[image]

Are there other settings to enable the iframing of Napili community?